# Check if photo gallery is empty

Tags: ios, swift, camera, gallery, is-empty

I want to load photos from my photo gallery to my UIImageView using Swift. Now I want to check if the gallery is empty or not. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Photos framework.

To see how many photos there are you can do something like this:

```
   import Photos

   ...

   PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
       if status == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
           var result: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: nil)
           NSLog("%d", Int(result.count))
       }
   }
```

If you want Photos and Videos:

```
 PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
    if status == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
       let options = PHFetchOptions()
       options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %i OR mediaType = %i", PHAssetMediaType.Image.rawValue, PHAssetMediaType.Video.rawValue)

       var allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(options)
    }
 }
```

You can also look to includeAssetSourceTypes property of PHFetchOptions. You can select TypeUserLibrary, TypeCloudShared or TypeiTunesSynced.

Comment: Do you also know how to use PHAsset for Photos and Videos combined? Now I want to check both and the fetchAssetsWithMediaType only takes one parameter e.g. .Image.